# Look up a number between 2 column to pull a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently have a formula that works only partly and rest of the work is manual. I look up a number  and then its spits out an optimized number

```
Device#=Column G
Optimized #=Column AZ
Optimized Replaced=Column BA
Optimized Removal #=BB

=XLOOKUP([@[Device '#]],Optimized[Replacing '#],Optimized[New '#])
```

With my formula, It only will look for the number in column BA, but id like to also look up the numbers in column bb and pull that value out.
[image]

Comment: In the same cell?, something like `concatenate` or `&`

Comment: >>pull that value out<< Did you want to fill each values in BA to each cell?

Comment: yes BA and BB are manual entries.

Answer (score 0):

as @gns100 suggest :

```
=XLOOKUP([@[Device '#]],Optimized[Replacing '#],Optimized[New '#])&XLOOKUP([@[Device '#]],Optimized[Removal '#],Optimized[New '#])
```

should do. Please share if it works/not. ( :